# Clustering images

Tags: clustering, matrix, conv-neural-network, image-processing

I do have about 700 matrices (200*200 pixels) and I would like to cluster them into 5-10 groups.

I wanted to try the k-medoids method for this but am not sure how to implement it. According to what I found out I would have to convert the 200*200 matrix into a 40000 element vector and then use that as input to the clustering. However I am not very convinced about the ability of this algorithm to handle such high dimensional data.

I read about convolutional neural networks and it seemed more suitable. However I would like to know if there is maybe a simpler algorithm that could do the job instead.

Comment: This is certainly broad, but given the upvoted & accepted answer, I don't think it is *too broad* to be answerable. I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Images clustering using the pixels as features is very unlikely to work well. Standard practice is to embed the images in a feature space designed for images, then apply a clustering method on that feature space. Standard feature representations include HOG ([Histogram of Oriented gradients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients)) and [SIFT/SURF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) features. SIFT in particular is widely used for image search, which involves similar measurements of between image distances as for clustering.

You could use a convolutional neural network to embed the images in a lower dimensional space, then apply clustering in that space. It's a lot of work though. I wouldn't recommend it unless you already have experience with neural networks.

Comment: This answer let me to the right direction. I discovered that what I needed was to look at the similarity between my images (for example using the HOG method) and then do a clustering based on the distance only.

Answer (score 0):

Within Stanford's [Course on Convolutional Neural Networks](http://cs231n.github.io/) (CNN) you can find an implementation for k-Nearest Neighbor. I think the actual function for k-medoids can be applied to that.

The course will give you a good overview when to use CNN and why they are preferred over the nearest neighbor methods in general for larger datasets.